# WIX relative path ends up being too long

Tags: .net, windows, filesystems, wix

I am getting errors from `light.exe` that indicate it is having problems locating one of the files in my setup project. Turns out on the PC in question the relative path I am using exceeds 260 characters. At the moment Wix is set up something like this:

```
<File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1' Source='..\..\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
```

The problem I have is that the Wix install project is located in a folder such as `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\WixInstaller\WixInstallerProject` and `\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe`exists under the `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder` folder. When `light.exe` attempts to resolve the path the net result is `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\WixInstaller\WixInstallerProject\..\..\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe` which in my particular case happens to be over 260 characters. The correct absolute path for the exe would be `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe` which in my case would be under 260 characters, but because of the unnecessary inclusion of the `WixInstaller\WixInstallerProject\..\..\` part of the path it is then over this limit.

Is there any way that I can get `light.exe` to resolve `..\..\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe` as `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe` instead of `D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\WixInstaller\WixInstallerProject\..\..\Path\To\Built\Executable\FoobarAppl10.exe`?

I appreciate this is not a limitation in Wix per se, more of an underlying limitation in the way the APIs Wix is designed to utilise are built, however I need a solution to the problem that will allow me to fix this in my `.wxs` file. Yes shortening the path would work but the problem isn't really that the path is too long (because it isn't), it's that the syntax for relative paths adds the unnecessary middle section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything in `light.exe` today that will custom evaluate the path so that Path.Combine() doesn't choke when the whole thing is over 260 characters. As you note, it's a frustrating limitation in .NET Framework (and Windows Installer APIs will choke as well).

To work around the issue, I would recommend looking into `bind paths`. You could change your code to be something like:

```
<File Id='FoobarEXE' Source='!(bindpath.FooBarApp)\FoobarAppl10.exe' />
```

The on the command-line do something like:

```
light.exe -b FooBarApp=D:\Path\To\ProjectFolder\Path\To\Built\Executable
```

That will create the shortest paths. You can move relative paths from the command-line to the `File/@Source` as well (for example, move the `Built\Executable` part of the path). I think you'll find it's very flexible.

Comment: I've been doing something similar for a long time, but with WiX pre-processor variables like `Source='$(var.FooBarApp)\FoobarAppl10.exe'`. Is there a significant difference to doing it either way, or does it just have to do with using msbuild or not?

Comment: Nothing to do with MSBuild. It just when the variables are resolved and you'll find the bind paths are much more powerful, especially in advanced scenarios like patching or distributed builds.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this, looks like it will solve my problem. Cheers!

Comment: I've been looking at the bind paths documentation at [sourceforge](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/specifying_source_files.htm) but I'm a little confused how to define this in my `.wxs` - is there anywhere that discusses this? Thanks!

Comment: It's not in your .wxs file, you set them on command-line to light.exe.

Comment: Apologies, I've just realized I had misread the bit about the command line in your answer... will have another go. Cheers!