# MSI APIs does not support long filenames - How to shorten the file name?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7, wix3.6

I am using `Wix` to generate `MSI`

Wix is dynamically generating the `ComponentsGenerated.wxs` file from the project reference.

One of the DLL in the project is **having the longest name** as follow

```
  <Component Id="D5CF013A7A8C3FB9D1BD48B1996555DA" 
             Guid="{CBDB1BC0-F4EE-4824-B937-D9F66278F89A}">
     <File Id="8EDDC3C71F9C124B466555A59378747" 
            KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.dll" />
   </Component>
```

Here: var.BasePath = "C:\Work\Projects\WixProjects\InstallerProjects\Client"

Therefore, I was getting **file not found an error** while I try to build a Wix project.

I have moved my project to C drive. 
Now:  var.BasePath = "C:\Client\"

Error got resolved. But question is, what is the better way to fix it? I **do not want to move the project to C drive**. there must be a way to shorten the length of the file in `wix` I believe. if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't use Wix, but could it be the same issue mentioned here?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15435040/4181058

Comment: `mklink /J "C:\Client" "C:\Work\Projects\WixProjects\InstallerProjects\Client"` creates a directory junction (link) from `C:\Client` to your long path. You could now use `C:\Client` in place of the long path in WiX source.

Comment: What happened with this?

Comment: Accepted the answer, please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373835/unable-to-uninstall-the-application-which-is-installed-using-wix-installer

Comment: Just added an answer there, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***NTFS Policy***: This I have never tried, but in recent versions of Windows 10 (**`Version 1607 and up apparently`** - run "**`winver.exe`**") there is a new NT / group policy that you can try. The policy is: **`Enable NTFS long paths`**.
>
> ***Local Drives***: Enable the policy (procedure below) and perhaps do a **`reboot`**. Then remember to use **`local NTFS drives`** - preferring the system drive I'd say. Let us know the results? (just a quick comment?).

***Build Time Only***: *Seeing as you need these paths to compile and build and not to install, this might work?* You need to be careful though, or your package could contain too long paths to install downstream (might not compile, I am not sure). You need very good QA - obviously. I would go back to **`Windows 7`** to be honest - to really test things.

***Description***: *"Enabling NTFS long paths will allow manifested win32 applications and Windows Store applications to access paths beyond the normal 260 char limit per node."*

***Launch Conditions***: A generic mechanism to prevent installation on unsupported systems (for whatever reason) is the [MSI's launch conditions concept](https://blog.flexerasoftware.com/software-installation/2010/11/using-msi-launch-conditions-to-prevent-installation-on-unsupported-windows-platforms/).

***Policy: gpedit.msc***: Setting the Group Policy (**`NB! Only PRO version of Windows I think!`**):

1. Press <kbd>**Windows**</kbd> key and tap <kbd>**R**</kbd>, type **`gpedit.msc`** and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.
2. Go to: **`Local Computer Policy`** **`=>`** **`Computer Configuration`** **`=>`** **`Administrative Templates`** **`=>`** **`System`** **`=>`** **`Filesystem`**.
3. Double click the **`Enable NTFS long paths`** option. Enable it.

> **Disclaimer!** Side effects unknown.

[image: NTFS Policy]

---

***Simplified Markup***: One more thing. In a subjective opinion I find WiX markup to be slightly over-complicated for many things. The authors of WiX have taken the toolkit in an interesting direction by allowing auto-generation of "boilerplate attributes" (if that is a term). Please see this answer for more: **[Syntax for guids in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965)**

And here is a sample of **`simplified WiX markup`**:

```
<!-- Sample guid below, do not copy paste -->
<Component Id="File.dll" Guid="{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABC}">
  <File Id="File.dll" Name="File.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\File.dll" />
</Component>
```

versus

```
<Component>
  <File Source="..\File.dll" />
</Component>
```

---

***Links***:

- [Windows 10 “Enable NTFS long paths policy” option missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing)
- [What is the maximum character limit for file names in windows 10?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-character-limit-for-file-names-in-windows-10)